# Multiplying a dense vector by a sparse matrix in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there an easy way to multiply a sparse matrix and a dense tensor in tensorflow?
I tried

```
def sparse_mult(sparse_mat,dense_vec):
    vec = tf.zeros(dense_vec.shape, dense_vec.dtype)
    indices = sparse_mat.indices
    values = sparse_mat.values
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        num_vals = sess.run(tf.size(values))
    for i in range(num_vals):
        vec[indices[i,0]] += values[i] * dense_vec[indices[i,1]]
    return vec
```

But I get "TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment." I tried

```
def sparse_mult(sparse_mat,dense_vec):
    vec = tf.zeros(dense_vec.shape, dense_vec.dtype)
    indices = sparse_mat.indices
    values = sparse_mat.values
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        num_vals = sess.run(tf.size(values))
    for i in range(num_vals):
        vec = vec[indices[i,0]].assign(vec[indices[i,0]] + values[i] * dense_vec[indices[i,1]])
    return vec
```

and got "ValueError: Sliced assignment is only supported for variables."
Turning vec into a variable with `vec = tf.get_variable('vec', initializer = tf.zeros(dense_vec.shape, dense_vec.dtype))` gives the same error. Is there a not too memory intensive way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_tensor_dense_matmul) which was invented for this exact purpose. You don't need to create your own function. This code (tested):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.SparseTensor( indices = [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 3, 4 ] ],
                     values = tf.constant( [ 1.0, 10 ] ),
                     dense_shape = [ 5, 5 ] )
vec = tf.constant( [ [ 2.0 ], [ 3 ], [ 4 ], [ 5 ], [ 6 ] ] )
c = tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul( a, vec )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run( c )
    print( res )
```

will output:

> [[ 2.]
>    [ 0.]
>    [ 0.]
>    [60.]
>    [ 0.]]

---

For reference, my first answer was referring to [`tf.sparse_matmul()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_matmul), which somewhat confusingly [multiplies two *dense* matrices but with a specially designed algorithm for matrices with many zero values](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3246#issuecomment-231807152). It will choke on sparse_tensor arguments.

Comment: Just add an extra dimension with size 1 to the vector.

Comment: tf.sparse_matmul() is between two matrices, not a matrix and a vector. I tried saving the vector as another sparse matrix and doing this but this gives "TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("SparseTensor_6/indices:0", shape=(2, 2), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("SparseTensor_6/values:0", shape=(2,), dtype=float32), dense_shape=Tensor("SparseTensor_6/dense_shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements to a supported type."

Comment: My code for that is 
`a = tf.SparseTensor(indices = [[0,0],[1,1]], values = [1.0,1.0], dense_shape = [2,2])

b = tf.SparseTensor(indices = [[0,0],[1,0]], values = [1.0,1.0], dense_shape = [2,2])

tf.sparse_matmul(a,b,a_is_sparse = True, b_is_sparse = True)`

Comment: Ok let me experiment a bit.

Comment: Updated my answer. `tf.sparse_matmul()` (confusingly) does something else, you're right.

Comment: Sure, happy to help! :) Can you please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?